# Error installing language pack magento2 on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, magento2

I am trying to install a language pack for magento using ubuntu 14.04.
First I installed the language pack, after that i put it in the root of the magento installation.

[image]

Then in my ubuntu virtual box i navigated to the Magento root dir and there i ran this command  `bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d source_nl_NL.csv langpack nl_NL` 
But the output was not what i hoped it to be take a look:

[image]

In text:

```
InvalidArgumentException]                        

  Cannot open dictionary file: "source_nl_NL.csv".  


i18n:pack [-m|--mode="..."] [-d|--allow-duplicates] source pack locale
```

**Additional information:**

Machine Ubuntu 14.04

Magento version 2.0
php version running in virtualbox 5.6

Feel free to ask for more info in the comment section.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: Have you checked file permission

Comment: It was a permission issue @Shine solved it

Comment: Cheer's Please give me a up vote or can i update this as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the file have proper permission for it